# Javascript addEventListener to the dynamic button

Tags: javascript

Hi In my code I'll add some dynamic buttons. Before adding that I am adding an event listener as follows

```
document.querySelector("input[name='btn']").addEventListener("click", runFunction);
```

But I am getting "Cannot call method addEventListener of null' in chrome console. How can I add event listner to the element that is not exists yet in plain Javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a listener to an element that does not exist yet. Either execute your script at the end of the page (before body close tag) or this way:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector("input[name='btn']").addEventListener("click", runFunction);
};
```

document.querySelector() returns null if it doesn't find an element that matches the selector, and you can't invoke a method of a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in document ready. if you use jQuery you can do something like this

```
$( function() {

document.querySelector("input[name='btn']").addEventListener("click", runFunction);

});
```

or

> `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });`

if you do not use jquery, you can use window.onload or window.document.onload